# addClass based on attribute for/id relationships

Tags: jquery

I got this script half-working but need help finishing it off. My jQuery skills are weak at best.

I'm basically creating an interactive flow chart using jQuery to add an expand class. But I went in search of a solution that would be more elegant than 1000 individual addClass scripts.

HTML (I removed excessive stuff):

```
<div class="x">
  <div class="x">Question</div>
  <button for="question-1-yes-action" class="x">Yes</button>
  <button for="question-1-no-action" class="x">No</button>
</div>
<div class="x">
  <div id="question-1-yes-action" class="x">
    <div class="x">Answer Yes</div>
  </div>
  <div id="question-1-no-action" class="x">
    <div class="x">Answer No</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$(function() {
    var currentFlow = $("button").attr("for");
    $("button").click(function() {
        $( "div[ id=" + currentFlow + "]").addClass( "expand" );
    });
});
```

The idea was to identify the container that needed the "expand" class added to it based on the for/ID relationship. At first, I thought it worked! If I click "Yes" the "Answer Yes" will get the "expand" class added to it. However... if I click "No," the "Answer Yes" also gets the "expand" class added to it. So clearly I did something wrong. I just don't know what it is or if my logic will even succeed.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is nearly there, the issue you have is that you only set `currentFlow` once, when the page loads. It instead needs to be set when the `click` event happens, and it needs to read the `for` from the button which was clicked.

In addition, it's not good practice to create non-standard attributes in your HTML. In this case, `for`. If you want to store custom metadata in your HTML, use a `data` attribute instead.

Lastly, if you're going to select an element by its `id`, use an `id` selector, not an attribute selector.

Here's a working example with all these amendments incorporated:

```js
jQuery($ => {
  $('.action-button').on('click', e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.expand').removeClass('expand');
    let currentFlow = $(e.target).data("for");
    $(currentFlow).addClass('expand');
  });
});
```

```css
.answer { display: none; }
.answer.expand { display: block; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="question-container">
  <div class="question">Question</div>
  <button type="button" data-for="#question-1-yes-action" class="action-button">Yes</button>
  <button type="button" data-for="#question-1-no-action" class="action-button">No</button>
</div>
<div class="answer-container">
  <div id="question-1-yes-action" class="answer">
    <div>Answer Yes</div>
  </div>
  <div id="question-1-no-action" class="answer">
    <div>Answer No</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Note that I also replaced all your `x` classes with more meaningful names.

Comment: This was absolutely perfect. Thanks for the additional information, you're absolutely right.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to fetch the `for` attribute on click of the `button`. So that the script fetches the attribute of the clicked button.

In your case, by default the attribute of the first button is retrieved. I have modified the code as shown below:

```
$(function() {
    $("button").click(function() {
        var currentFlow = $(this).attr("for");
        $( "div[ id=" + currentFlow + "]").addClass( "expand" );
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(function() {
  $('button[for*="-action"]').click(function() {
    var id = $(this).attr('for');
    $('div[id*="-action"]').removeClass('expand');
    $('div[id="' + id + '"]').addClass('expand');
  });
});
```

```css
.expand {
  background-color: red;
  padding-bottom: 50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="x">
  <div class="x">Question</div>
  <button for="yes-action" class="x">Yes</button>
  <button for="no-action" class="x">No</button>
</div>

<div class="x">
  <div id="yes-action" class="action">
    <div class="x">Answer Yes</div>
  </div>
  <div id="no-action" class="action">
    <div class="x">Answer No</div>
  </div>
</div>
```